# How do I enable or configure "Code Folding" and Side-by-Side Text Compare in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

I have been using DBeaver for a lot of SQL Coding for about 5 weeks now, and I started using it in my training business too, because it is a nice multi-database editor.

I really like it, but there are 2 crucially important things that I have not been able to get working properly.   I am using the Community Edition.

Code Folding doesn’t work.  I’ve enabled it in the Preferences Panel, but it just doesn’t work.  My current program is over 500 lines of SQL and I really need the ability to hide (“fold”) major blocks of code so that I can jump to different parts of the script fast.  It really slows me down to not have code folding.

Text Compare – I frequently need to compare 2 versions of the same script.

Right now I have to move the code over to Notepad++ to work with large blocks of code or script files, and use either BeyondCompare or Notepad++ to compare two script files to see their differences.

Someone please help on these points, because code folding and file comparisons are functions that I depend upon heavily when coding.

Answer (score 3):

About "Code Folding", I managed to make it work by also enabling "Toggle Block Selection" from "Edit" menu (ALT+SHIFT+A). You can disable it once the folding items appear (next to BEGIN or DECLARE statements).

Comment: Thank you for answering.  The question is a popular one, and your answer helped solve it for over 1000 people so far.